# Easy list; Hide with FinalSpace

Tags: easylist

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
{\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
\dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
\@parboxrestore
\leftskip=\dimen@
\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
\begin{easylist}}
{\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
\unvbox\Easylist@box\par\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed,Progressive*=1cm,
Style1*=\textbullet,%
Style2*=$\ast$,%
Style3*=$\square$)

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\begin{Easylist}
      & First thingy
      && Second thingy
      &&& Third thingy
      &&&& Fourth thingy
\end{Easylist}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My idea is to have custom bullet style with a little bit of space between bullet and text. I have used function `FinalSpace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `Hide` to the number of entries you want to have no number (3 in your case it seems). To get the additional spacing, you can add `\hspace` to your styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
{\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
\dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
\@parboxrestore
\leftskip=\dimen@
\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
\begin{easylist}}
{\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
\unvbox\Easylist@box\par\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=3,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed,Progressive*=1cm,
Style1*=\textbullet\hspace{2em},%
Style2*=$\ast$\hspace{2em},%
Style3*=$\square$\hspace{2em})

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\begin{Easylist}
      & First thingy
      && Second thingy
      &&& Third thingy
      &&&& Fourth thingy
\end{Easylist}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]